# Batch file access denied

Tags: batch-file, task, command-prompt

I'm trying to run a batch file to trigger a task every 3 minutes but when I try to execute, the prompt display error of Access is denied.

Here is the script:

```
@echo off


call :subroutine1


:subroutine1
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 3 /tn Process /tr notepad.exe >> C:\Users\Dee\Desktop\log
```

can someone explain what is the problem in here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you run that `schtasks` command from the command line manually? If not, you can't run it from a batch file.

Comment: manually the task can be done, but using script, access is denied

Comment: The only way that could happen is if the batch file is running under a different user account that does not have admin privileges.

Comment: but the current account which I'm currently using to do the task schedule is an admin account

Comment: It works here for both admins and non admins., at least the only relevant code which is the last line.

Comment: I execute in the command prompt and it return "Access is denied" I remove the path written on the behind, it is successful, but I don't know where is the file created for the task